# Something strange with material slots

Tags: materials, shaders

I have an object with a material in the active material slot. When i add a second one an d bring that above the first one, noting happens i still only see the material that was first applied, it seems as the order of the slot doesn't matter. Why does this happens?

Best regards
Asta

Comment: Hello, you change the order of the slots but in order to change the color of a face you need to change the material in the slot or assign it another material that is in another slot

Answer (score 7):

When you first add a material slot to an object, the material you put in there automatically shows on all faces by default because it is the only one.

But this is not like an override material which is put on the object surface regardless of the faces. So as soon as you add it, it gets assigned to all faces.

Adding a second material slot does not automatically assign this to any faces, you have to do it manually. And in the same way as the order of multiple material slots does not matter *(just imagine the chaos if you want for some reason change the material order in the slots and it messes up all the face assignments on the object)*, now after the first material slot has been assigned to the faces, you have to manually assign the other material to them if you want to change the "base" material.

Of course a simpler way to do this would be just change the material in the first slot to the new material and put the first material in the second slot.

To say it clear because using the term "material" can be misleading: if you have an object with no material and **no material slots**, the first **slot** you add will be automatically assigned to all faces (yes, even if there is no material in it), all following material **slots** have to be assigned manually to faces.

Changing the order of the slots later is just a matter of for example organizing your materials on a multi-material object, maybe you want them in a specific order like alphabetically, or first all plastic materials then all metal materials, or first all shades of blue then all shades of red etc. And you most likely don't want this order to change the materials on the mesh.