# Add material to polygon selection, impossible?

Tags: materials

Polygons selected

[image]

Material assigned to selection
[image]

Material is not confined to selection for some reason, why?
[image]

Another example: Add Material Slot to Selected polygons, assign Material Slot to selection, applies the material to the entire object, ignoring the selection, what is the problem here?
[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as a face without a material; *every* face has a material.  If you have only a single material slot on your object, all faces will use that material.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to assign a material to a selected group of polygons in an object? 

That adding a material slot and assigning it to selected polygons, doesn't actually assign a material slot to the selected polygons? 

So why do the interface elements that appear to intend doing exactly that exist if they don't actually do anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Make *two* material slots.  Assign faces to one slot or to the other.

Comment: My answer here explains the material slot behavior a bit detailed: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292434/something-strange-with-material-slots/292436#292436