Emission Material Not Assigning to Selected Faces
Im having a hard time getting colored polygons using the emission shader.  I will link the blend file as well.
I go into edit mode and select the faces, then I create a new material and change the node to Emission with a strength of 1.  Then I hit assign and change the viewport to show the material but there is nothing ... no matter what color I use as well.
Here's the file, I really hope someone can help me out I'm going crazy over this:


Hello, it seems to work: https://zupimages.net/up/24/20/hflz.jpg

did you change to material or rendered view? if this still doesn't work, i would recommend making a video what you did or describe really step by step what you did.

Working fine here assuming you're just intending to add the colour to the whole of your body (Cube) object. If you just want to colour some faces of it you should add a default colour for the whole object then add another material with your Emission colour with the '+' button, select the required faces, and assign the colour to them.

In the download file it is working. By the way, when you have a single material on the object, you don't need to assign it to faces. The first material slot will by default be used for all faces. But this also means you cannot assign it to only some of the faces - you cannot have faces with no material if there is one present on the object. Well, to be precise you cannot have faces with no material slot assigned to it - but this slot can be empty if you remove the material from it. More in-depth information on this in my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292434/

I don’t know why mine looks like an unlit grey transparent ghost then.  I’m not sure if it’s a graphics card thing or what.  I’m so confused why mine looks the way it does and you guys open it and it’s just fine as was what I was intending to do.

I've got a sneaky feeling about the internal face on the mirror-plane (some intermittent anomalous behaviour with Bisect..)  But. probably not relevant

Ok so I figured it out.  It’s a weird solution but hopefully it helps others.
What I did was went into the render properties and selected, “high quality” using the Eevee renderer and it magically showed the material that was applied.
