Image texture not showing up in shader viewport
My image texture isn't showing up in the shader viewport at all. Its really the most simple node tree too which is why I'm so confused. I did unwrap the uv already too.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75816/how-to-distinguish-material-and-material-slot/75820#75820 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

You material isn't assigned to any faces,

And here specifically explaining among other things why your new material is not automatically showing on the object: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292434/something-strange-with-material-slots/292436#292436
